# Import export as ACP in alfresco share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am not able to find Import and Export as ACP option in Alfresco share 5.0. In earlier versions I used to do it via exporer but as it  is no longer avilable in this version how can we do import export contents as ACP files?

Answer (score 3):

You're right, the deprecation of Explorer caused many headaches to me too.
It seems that the usual operation has been replaced by [Importing Module Data](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/dev-extensions-modules-importing-module-data.html) feature, at least for modules.

> You can import the data by using an XML file or an ACP file as part of your module's initialization.
>
> First place your ACP or XML file somewhere in your module's classpath.
>   Often this will be within the config folder structure. Next add the
>   following configuration to your module-context.xml file, specifying
>   either the XML or ACP file by its location on the classpath.

It also seems that alfresco is going to reinstate some features on version 5.1 as forecasted by [Jeff Potts blog article](http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2014/11/06/3962).

Comment: Thanks abarisone. Well Module Import is of no use because there is no way we can do export :) Hopefully they reinstate in 5.1 but I am stuck for now :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is already useful but there is an excellent add-on to import and export in acp for multiple versions. It's compatible with 5.0. You can download it here : 
https://github.com/atolcd/alfresco-share-import-export

Paste the jar file in your tomcat/shared/lib/ folder and restart Alfresco and let's go.